# How do I configure a custom client socket factory for RMI in Java 7?

Tags: java, sockets, rmi

I have written a custom client socket factory for RMI, so that if direct socket connections are not available due to firewalls, I fall back to HTTP. This worked great with Java 6. In Java 7, when I call RMISocketFactory.setSocketFactory( mySocketFactory ), I get this error message:

java.net.SocketException: factory already defined

Calling RMISocketFactory.getSocketFactory() shows that the installed factory is an instance of com.sun.deploy.net.protocol.rmi.DeployRMISocketFactory. I can't use the default HTTP fallback mechanism, because I've customized the URLs for http connections (I can't use the /cgi/java-rmi path).

Why is Java 7 pre-installing a socket factory, when setSocketFactory() is defined as only being able to be called once per process? How can I get it to use my own socket factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using per-object socket factories via the RMIClientSocketFactory mechanism introduced in 1.2 last century.

Comment: Are you referring to the UnicastRemotObject.exportObject constructor that takes an RMIClientSocketFactory parameter? I'm not really clear on how to use that, because my client knows the external hostname/address of the server; the server doesn't know its own external IP address or hostname. How can I make it so that my RMIClientSocketFactory uses parameters supplied by the client to establish the socket to the server?

Comment: @JesseBarnum The server should use the java.rmi.server.hostname property if the stub isn't being built with the correct IP address. Or your socket factory could read some system property set by the client.